# Android Studio has no PreviewView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camerax

I am trying to implement a camera in my app, and am following the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview). I am stuck at the part where I have to add a PreviewView to my layout, as I am unable to find it in the editor as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTazp.jpg).

I have also copied and pasted the dependencies from the guide onto my app's build.grade as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwW9l.jpg). I have restarted Android Studio multiple times but PreviewView still does not show up in the layout editor. It however shows up if I try to import it in the Activity file.

I am using 2021.1.1 Patch 3.

Comment: if you copy paste the actual view, does it pick up ? `<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
       android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
`

Comment: It works now if I paste the view in XML. I did the same before but for some reason it did not work (the Design tab would not update). I updated my Android Studio to the latest version before I tried the copy and paste again; not sure if that plays a part.